# Firebase Crashlytics Issue Closing

Tags: firebase, crashlytics

I want to close the issue on Firebase Crashlytics by using functions of Firebase/API but unable to find any example or document which can guide me in this.

**What I want: --** 
We have webhooks which report issue is close on our project management tool as soon as developer close the issue we hit the API/Firebase Functions to close it on Firebase Crashlytics  Dashboard also.

Now we have to manage it manually by opening the Firebase Crashlytics Panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase does not provide such API or SDK function to close

Comment: Hi @pawansgi92, where did you find that firebase SDK is not support such API? Are there some notes in official documentation?